# Dynamic text in HTML page without iFrames

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple text file stored on my server(domain.com/text.txt) which contains an HTML string like **text text**.
It can be also an XML file or whatever suits for this issue.

On a different server which I cannot access, I have an html page (which I can edit). I want to have on this page a call to take the code from the text/xml file without using iFrames or Jquery, and inject it to the main HTML page.
What will be the best way to do it?

Comment: Without Javascript or a server-side language, you can't.

Comment: Are you trying to do this specifically in javascript as opposed to doing this server side?

Comment: ajax to fetch the content, js to manipulate into html, insert it ino the DOM to show the end-user

Comment: What have you tried? This question can be answered pretty easy with a google search. You could use Ajax to retrieve the data and then javascript to apply the response to your dom.

Comment: Plain Javascript is ok, JQ not :). I didn't try nothing yet, wanted to know what will be best approach before the frustration phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this in javascript, you'll want to use an ajax call (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to get the contents of the file.  You can then parse that text and add it to the page however you'd like.

For instance, if you just want to grab some text and stick it in a text box, it would look like this:

```
<textarea id="ta"> </textarea>
<script>
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById('ta').innerHTML( xmlhttp.responseText );
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://domain.com/text.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

It would be much simpler to do this with jQuery, but since you specifically said no jQuery, I went the old-fashioned route.

Can't be much more specific than that without more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: If this solution was helpful to you, would you mind marking my answer as accepted? http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png